# Non-convergence of sequence and existence of subsequence with special property

Tags: general-topology

If the sequence $(x_{n})$ doesn't converge to $x_0 \in X$ then there exists subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ so that there is no subsequence of that subsequence that converges to $x_0$.
(or: If the sequence $(x_{n})$ doesn't converge to $x_0 \in X$ then there exists subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ so that $x_0$ is not accumulation point of that subsequence)

(I hope I didn't confused anyone, I'm translting this from Croatian)

My idea for solution:

Let suggest that for every subsequence there is subsequence that converges to $x_0$. That means that $x_0$ is an accumulations point for every subseqence of $(x_n)$. *And now that would mean it is a limit point*

And I'm stuck and I think I'm going in circles with this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to note that the fact that $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x_0$ means there is some open set $U$ containing $x_0$ and arbitrarily large $i$ so that $x_i$ is not in $U$. You could use this to construct a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that does not intersect $U$ at all, and then there is no way any subsequence of $(x_{n_k})$ could converge to $x_0$.

You could also use the above paragraph to get a subsequence that gives you the contradiction you are looking for in your approach, but it is probably cleaner to just prove this directly.

Comment: There is $U$ neighbourhood of $x_0$ so that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is $n'>n$ and $x_{n'}$ is not in $U$ (that is negation of convergence, right?). Now I put that in subsequence and it's easy to prove that $x_0$ can't be accumulation point.  (just cheking if my conclusion is right? =D) And thank you =)

Comment: Yes! You just have to be a bit careful when you pick your subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that each $n_k<n_{k+1}$.

Comment: I know, I know =) Function $n:$$\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ must be monotonically increasing. Thank you =)